# possible to target Kindle Fire ebook?

Tags: css, epub

Is anyone aware of a method of feeding the Kindle Fire (ebooks) a separate style-sheet?  One that would not be read by iBooks (iPad)?

I am aware of the method (below) that allows you to target the old Kindle

```
<style type="text/css" media="amzn-mobi">
    p.firstline {margin-top:20px;text-indent:-40px}
    p.line {text-indent:-40px}
</style>
```

But I'm looking for a way of targeting Kindle Fire only.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

According to the [George Benthien](http://www.gbenthien.net/Kindle%20and%20EPUB/KindleFire.html) you can use @media amzn-kf8 for Kindle Fire. Hope this helps.

Those media queries apply only to eBooks, it doesn't work for HTML.

I was looking for web solution, and resorted to device sniffing via JS.

This is what I have done with jQuery:
`if( /Silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       $('html').addClass('kindle');
      }`

And then in CSS:
`html {font-size:143.75%; }
html.kindle{font-size:112.5%}`

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read Kindle/Fire uses a webkit browser so it is pretty standard compliant ( a list of supported HTML and CSS for Kindle can be found here: [kindleformatting.com/book/files/KindleHTMLtags.pdf](http://kindleformatting.com/book/files/KindleHTMLtags.pdf))

You could do the reverse and target Safari Mobile and make certain elements display differently in Safari Moble. (iPad)

```
#content  { float : left; }
[if SafMob]#content  { float : none; }
```

More information on conditional css can be found [here](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced). But I think you're out of luck on targeting the Kindle specifically, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for this. But yeah I was specifically looking for a Kindle Fire target.  And not just for its web browser, but for the ebook reader.

Comment: My point was, I don't think you can target the kindle at all. Sorry if I wasn't very clear. And Amazon is being pretty hush hush about what browser framework they actually use, adding to the problem of finding out how to.

Comment: In the end I've managed to use some media queries to instead target the iPad, and this seems to have worked well.